# how to stop preg_match_all returning full pattern matches number?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code to get all the img tag:

```
<?php

foreach($design_children as $design_child) {
    echo preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $design_child->post_content, $result);
    echo $result[0];
    break;
}

?>
```

but I keep getting the pattern matches number return to 
my output like 2, 3 next to my images 
how do I remove it ???!!

Comment: Change `echo preg_match_all(...);` to be just `preg_match_all(...)`.  Then check to see if `$result` is populated, and don't echo it if not to prevent warnings.

Comment: ooops silly me .. :s thanks a lot man !! it works now !

Comment: You're welcome, come back soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `echo` before `preg_match_all`.